# !arraylist.contains() not working?

Tags: java, arraylist, conditional-statements, contains

Basically I need to add strings from one arraylist to another in a specific order.
First items that contain both favorites, then then first favorite, then the second.

I´ve been trying to do this by adding the first set (no problems), and then adding the second set with a conditional: originalList[i].contains(favorite1)&&!secondList.contains(originalListNames[i])

But I kept getting repeats. I then tried the code below, and I STILL get repeats. Theyre being added in the correct order, and all the things that SHOULD get added, do get added. But they really shouldnt be getting repeated, yet they do.... any help here as to what exactly I'm screwing up?

```
    ArrayList<String> dataSource = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if (categories[i].toLowerCase().contains(favorite1)) {
            if (categories[i].toLowerCase().contains(favorite2)) {
                dataSource.add(names[i] + "," + dates[i] + "," + descriptions[i] + "," + categories[i] + "," + imgurl[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if (categories[i].toLowerCase().contains(favorite1)) {
            if (dataSource.contains(names[i])) {
            }
            else{
                dataSource.add(names[i] + "," + dates[i] + "," + descriptions[i] + "," + categories[i] + "," + imgurl[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that dataSource is the destination, and names, dates, descriptions, etc are arrays that contain strings all corresponding to the same index. (that is, names[i], dates[i], etc. all contain the same thing

Comment: Dagnabbit.....already see the issue.....i need to be searching for a substring in dataSource, not the entire string. From my understanding, I need to iterate through dataSource applying arrayList[i].toString().contains(substring) ?


An aside, i know i can do the above code shorter, I was just trying to work it out in more basic steps because I had thought that for some reason the !a.contains() wasnt working.

Comment: maybe try using a `Map` then

Comment: Try `.eqauls()` instead of `contains()` maybe.

Comment: did you try indexOf ?

Comment: Gonna look switching to a Map later, but for now iterating each element and then calling the equivalents of !contains worked.

.equals() wouldnt work because im searching for a substring. Im basically adding comma seperated values as a single value in an arraylist and then needing to looking within that, which is why I had issues to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

So finally got it....thanks for the help. Bit rusty on my java, but the final result (nonoptimized though it may be....):

```
    for (int i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if (categories[i].toLowerCase().contains(favorite1)) {
            boolean found=false;
            for (int j=0; j < dataSource.size(); j++){
                if (dataSource.get(j).toString().indexOf(names[i]) >= 0) {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (!found){
                dataSource.add(names[i] + "," + dates[i] + "," + descriptions[i] + "," + categories[i] + "," + imgurl[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```